# Lightning out App error in callback function in aura component created from vfp

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events, callback

I have a vfp as below called from a related list button which create an aura component:

```
$Lightning.use("c:LA03_SendFormToContact", function() {        
            $Lightning.createComponent("c:LC15_SendFormToContact",
                                       {
                                           "selectedContacts" : selectedToArray[0],
                                           "recordId": "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}"
                                       },
                                       "SendFormToClient",
                                       function(cmp) {
                                           $A.eventService.addEventHandler({                                                                                        
                                               event: 'force:showToast',
                                               handler: function(event) {
                                                   if (sforce && sforce.one) {    
                                                       console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
                                                       sforce.one.showToast({                                                       
                                                           "title": event.$b.title,                                                       
                                                           "message": event.$b.message,                                                       
                                                           "type": event.$b.type,
                                                           "duration": 6000
                                                       });
                                                   }
                                               }
                                           });
                                           $A.eventService.addEventHandler({                                                                                        
                                               event: 'force:navigateToURL',
                                               handler: function(event) {
                                                   if (sforce && sforce.one) {    
                                                       console.log('event url : '+event.$b.url);
                                                       window.parent.location.href = event.$b.url;                                                   
                                                   }
                                               }
                                           });
                                           console.log('Lightning Component created');
                                       });
        });
```

I added eventHandler to catch event from the aura component.

Here the code which fires a navigateToUrl event on callback of controller method :

```
sendMail : function(component, event, helper) {
    
    console.log("In send mail action");        
    
    var toContact = component.get("v.toContact");
    
    if(!toContact || toContact == "")
    {
        component.set("v.toContactValidity",false);
    }
    else
    {
        var toUser = component.get("v.toUser"); 
        var ccUser = component.get("v.ccUser");
        var ccContact = component.get("v.ccContact");        
        var bccUser = component.get("v.bccUser");
        var bccContact = component.get("v.bccContact");            
        let toEmails = [];
        if(toUser.length > 0){
            for(var i = 0; i < toUser.length; i++){
                toEmails.push(toUser[i]);
            }
        }
        if(toContact.length > 0){
            for(var i = 0; i < toContact.length; i++){
                toEmails.push(toContact[i]);
            }
        }
        
        let ccEmails = [];
        if(ccUser.length > 0){
            for(var i = 0; i < ccUser.length; i++){
                ccEmails.push(ccUser[i]);
            }
        }
        if(ccContact.length > 0){      
            for(var i = 0; i < ccContact.length; i++){                
                ccEmails.push(ccContact[i]);
            }
        }
        
        let bccEmails = [];
        if(bccUser.length > 0){
            for(var i = 0; i < bccUser.length; i++){
                bccEmails.push(bccUser[i]);
            }
        }
        if(bccContact.length > 0){      
            for(var i = 0; i < bccContact.length; i++){                
                bccEmails.push(bccContact[i]);
            }
        }
        
        var emailSubject = component.get("v.subject");
        var emailBody = component.get("v.body");
        var relatedTo = component.get("v.recordId");
        var files = component.get("v.selected");
        var fileIds = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
            fileIds.push(files[i].file.Id);
        }
        console.log("file");
        console.log(fileIds);
        var action = component.get("c.sendEmailApex");
        action.setParams({
            "toAddress" : toEmails,
            "ccAddress" : ccEmails,
            "bccAddress" : bccEmails,
            "relatedTo" : relatedTo,
            "subject" : emailSubject,
            "body" : emailBody,
            "files" : fileIds
        });
        component.set("v.isMainModalOpen",false);
        component.set("v.showSpinner",true);
        
        /*action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            console.log("In call back of notify component on send emails");
            var state = response.getState();
            console.log(state);
            component.set("v.showSpinner",false);
            if(state === "SUCCESS"){  
                console.log("In success");                                
                var navService = component.find("navService");
                // Sets the route to /lightning/r/Account/{acctid}/view
                var pageReference = {
                    type: 'standard__recordPage',
                    attributes: {
                        recordId: component.get("v.recordId"),
                        objectApiName: "Account",
                        actionName: "view"
                    }
                };
                console.log(pageReference);
                navService.navigate(pageReference);*/
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            console.log("In call back of notify component on send emails");
            var state = response.getState();
            console.log(state);
            component.set("v.showSpinner",false);
            if(state === "SUCCESS"){  
                console.log("In success");                                
                var event = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
                event.setParams({
                    "url" : "/lightning/r/Account/"+component.get("v.recordId")+"/view",
                });
                event.fire();
                console.log('after fire url');
                var successMessage = $A.get("$Label.c.sfdc_sendForm_successMessage");
                var successToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                successToast.setParams({
                    "title" : "Success!",
                    "message" : successMessage,
                    "type" : "success"
                });
                successToast.fire(); 
                
                
                
            }else if(state === "ERROR"){                
                component.set("v.isMainModalOpen",true);
                console.log("In error");
                var errors = response.getError();
                if(response.getError()[0].message == 'SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: EMAIL_ADDRESS_BOUNCED, Email address marked as bounced: contact_r1@gmail.com: [toAddresses, contact_r1@gmail.com]')
                {
                    errors[0].message = 'Email of the account is invalid' 
                }
                console.log(errors);                
                var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    "title" : "Error!",
                    "message" : errors[0].message,
                    "type" : "error"
                });
                toastEvent.fire();
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action); 
    }
},
```

The aura application :

```
<aura:application description="SendFormToContact application" extends="ltng:outApp" access="global" implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess">
<aura:dependency resource="c:LC15_SendFormToContact"/>
<!-- Load the navigation events in the force namespace. -->
<aura:dependency resource="markup://force:*" type="EVENT"/>
```

</aura:application>

I'm getting this error when navigatetoURL event is fired :

[image]

Does someone know how can I fix this error ?

Comment: Does your dependency app `c:LA03_SendFormToContact` have those events as dependencies? You need to be specific about which dependencies you import; if they are not imported from an app directly (e.g., with `aura:registerEvent`), you need to make sure you include those in your dependency markup.

Comment: Yes i just putted the aura application, as you can see I'm using `<aura:dependency resource="markup://force:*" type="EVENT"/>`